# Highlight rows having same value(Email address)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I have two separate excel files with email addresses.
File A(4000 rows) has email addresses and size of mailbox and File B has only email addresses(700 rows).

So I need to highlight all the 700 rows in File A so that I can get the mailbox size.

I tried to use spreadsheet compare and it was not helpful.Kindly show me a way to do this.

Comment: Put all the data into 1 workbook, with 2 worksheets (1 for your 4,000 rows and 1 for your 700 rows), and then use conditional formatting to look for patterns.

Comment: If the final information wanted is the mailbox size of each of the 700 e-mails, look into `VLOOKUP`, if it is total mailbox size, look into `SUMIF`

Comment: Since you are tying to get the Mail box size then no use of highlighting rows,, use Lookup formula to get Mail box size from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2 for common Mail IDs. So please [Edit] your post and change the Title of the question,!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I solved it using Conditional Formatting and setting a rule:

- First we need to select column (eg. A) of Sheet 1
- Then on Home tab press the Conditional Formatting button > New rule > use a formula
- Then we enter the formula:

  =COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A:$A,A1)

So we check if the value from A1 exists in Sheet 2 Column A.

If at least one exists, it will be highlighted by the format which we specify (press the format button).

Note: I did this in a single file by creating another sheet and pasting the data of the second excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming FileA is Sheet1 (Column A & B occupied)and FileB is Sheet2(Column A occupied). Put this in B1 :

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!A:A,0))
```

and drag downwards.

explaination/more info > https://exceljet.net/formula/basic-index-match-exact

please share if it works/not.

Comment: will give it a try later and let you know.